# JavaFX rotate screen 180°

Tags: javafx, openjfx

I'm working on an application, that's going to be running on an embedded device, but I'm having problems, as the screen on the said device is mounted upside-down.

I found that I could do the `rotate="180"` in the FXML, but the thing is that drop down doesn't change and is still rotated.

Any idea how I should rotate the screen?

PS. Underlying OS is Linux, but it's not running any X servers, so I can't really rotate it OS wise.

PPS. Even when I do rotate it using `xrandr`, the framebuffer freaks out and doesn't render full frames, so I get the "old WinXP frozen app drawing" ability.

Comment: I'd say this is something that should be configured at the OS level. I once had to do that for my Raspberry PI and it was just a config option.

Comment: On RPi it's easy, but not on the board we're using. We're using colibri imx6 and it doesn't have any of those options anywhere.